# Generalised linear models error distribution (continuous response)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, continuous-data, error-propagation

I'm a bit confused about what error distribution I should use for the generalised linear models that I am running. My response variable is litter decay rate (k) (continuous, which runs from -1.5 to +1.6) and my predictors are litter treatment and arthropod exclusion/inclusion (type). As I only have 5 blocks in my experiment I have decided to run GLMs not linear mixed models:

glm(Litter.decay.rate.k~Type + Treatment + Type*Treatment + Block, data=mb6)

The data is normally distributed.

The output show that the data is under-dispersed (Residual deviance: 2.5906 on 35 degrees of freedom). I don't really understand what error distribution I should be using as a result.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data are Gaussian and you are estimating the dispersion (you are given the code you show) then the data can't be over or under dispersed (See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdispersion#Normal_distribution).

If the distribution of `Litter.decay` given/conditional upon the values of the predictor variables is Gaussian then you can fit the model as you did, or better via `lm()` (you don't need the iterative algorithm for a Gaussian GLM with identity link function as you fitted here.)

I have often found data like rates or stable isotopes exhibit a mean variance relationship not accounted for by the Gaussian, where the mean and the variance are separate parameters and the LM or Gaussian GLM assumes constant variance. In such instances, fitting a model with a linear predictor for the mean **and** the variance (i.e. you have a model with two prediction equations, one for the mean [the bit you already fitted] and another for the variance).

Such location-scale models fall into several broad classes of models:

- the class of Vector GLMS of [Yee & Wild (1996)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2345888)
- the class of Generalised Additive Models for Location, Scale, Shape of [Rigby & Stasinopolous (2005)](http://doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9876.2005.00510.x)